# Live status in menulet

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm building a Mac OS X app that has a main window and a menulet. The menulet has a menu with two buttons and some status text.

Sometimes my app is running a timer and I'd like to update the menulet status text according to the timer (e.g. not running, 00:15:13, 00:07:02) including live countdown when the timer is running.

Does anybody know how to live update my menulet? I know it's possible since both many Apple apps and e.g. dropbox updates the menulet menu live.

Thanks in advance!

/Tokke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `setTitle:` method

```
[statusItem setTitle:statusItemTitle];
```

Comment: Is that possible to do with the menulet code in a separate file?